# Double tap Gesture on UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to double tap on the UICollectionViewCell to like the profile just like **OkCupid App**. I have applied Tap Gesture on Collection View but it does not work.

When I try to double tap the cell every time `didSelectCollectionViewCell` Method call.

Answer (score 3):

The error which you got: Cannot call value of non-function type 'UICollectionView!' is because you have try to use wrong method.

Please try to use this one:

```
var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(pointInCollectionView)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the double tap gesture recognizer to the collection view instead of the cell. In its action selector you could determine which cell was double tapped

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     var doubleTapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didDoubleTapCollectionView:")
     doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2  // add double tap
     self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGesture)
}

func didDoubleTapCollectionView(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     var pointInCollectionView: CGPoint = gesture.locationInView(self.collectionView)
     var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath = self.collectionView(forItemAtPoint: pointInCollectionView)
     var selectedCell: UICollectionViewCell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath)
     // Rest code
}
```

Comment: The above code gives an error Cannot call value of non-function type 'UICollectionView!'

Comment: sounds like error in your collectionview check your collectionview

Comment: These methods above do not exist, please provide valid compilable code when replying in order to not confuse other beginner developers.

Answer (score 1):

have you set the `UITapGestureRecognizer` property `numberOfTapsRequired:` to 2?

Answer (score -1):

apply the **UITapGesture** on **UICollectionviewcell** instead of **UIcollectionView** and handle the selection in custom UICollectionViewCell and set the property numberofTapsRequired equal to 2 .....