# Best principles for adding gesture recognizers in swift ios apps

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am working on a grid based game (like minesweeper). It is a 2d grid that I am displaying using a UICollectionView that contains a set of custom UICollectionViewCell cells.

I want to be able to listen to touch events on individual cells. Is it fine to add an UITapGestureRecognizer() to each of the cells (on a 20x20 board, for example). Or is there a better way?

I understand from Ahmad's reply that using this works for single taps:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
}
```

However, I want different event handlers for single vs double taps on the cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to let the base container as a UICollectionView (which I find it a good idea), I doubt that you need to add UITapGestureRecognizer to it, all you have to do is to let your class (Controller) to conforms to [UICollectionViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate) its *Delegate* and implement [collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618032-collectionview?language=objc).

Also, the benefit that you'll get when implementing this method is you can easily determine which cell has been selected, by checking what is the `indexPath.row` of the selected cell, as follows:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
}
```

*Don't forget to:*

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource { //...
```

**EDIT:**

In case of you want to add a *double tap* functionality to your collection view, I suggest to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939214/double-tap-gesture-on-uicollectionviewcell) to achieve it.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you. This was super helpful. Much appreciated.

Comment: @sridhar Glad to help. btw, if this answer is the right one for your question you should accept it, that will gives you +2 points, gives me +15 points and the most important thing is letting the viewers know that this is the solution.